# restoring from glacier before it was s3 glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I was backing up my synology to glacier.  I've restored to another synology before no problem.  the synology just bricked, and before i buy another solution i'd like to get my glacier restored on some other device in the meantime.  I see its now called S3 Glacier and the tools that seemed to exist previously have changed or are gone? And it seems like glacier is just a S3 back up now?

What is the simplest tool i can use to restore these files. to something else?  Doesn't have to be free.  Happy to restore it to a bucket.

Also any insight into the product change would help too.

Comment: S3 Gacier is a service build on top of glacier storage class and provides a lot of features (volts, access policies, lock policies, ...). If you are interested in only glacier storage class, then you use S3 service, not S3 Glacier. Check for your files in your S3 bucket where you backed-up your files.

Comment: @Marcin that's not quite accurate.  S3 Glacier is identical to the old service formerly called Glacier, which is what S3 uses to implement the Glacier storage class but otherwise has nothing to do with S3 as far as anyone outside AWS can tell.  They just renamed in an ill-conceived move that can't possibly result in anything but confusion... as is the case here.  It's a bad design choice, but the [Synology device directly uses Glacier](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/GlacierBackup/help) which is now called S3 Glacier despite having no relevant connection with S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @PompeyMagnus nothing changed that I know of, just the silly rename.  There were never any real tools for Glacier, since it's so low level and meant to be accessed from a system that manages backups and their catalogs.  It was never possible, for example, to download files from Glacier using the console, so I'm wondering what specific things are you having trouble finding?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i wish i could remember the names.  but i guess if its still working like it was i should be ok thanks.